# Clock picker in jquery not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I need to display a clock picker in the aspx page. 
My code is like below.

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="clockpicker-gh-pages/dist/bootstrap-clockpicker.min.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div class="input-group clockpicker">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" value="18:00"/>
                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span>
                    </span>

  <script>
   $(document).ready(function () {
$('.clockpicker').clockpicker({
                placement: 'top',
                align: 'left',
                donetext: 'Done'
            });
});
function pageLoad() {
            $('.clockpicker').clockpicker({
                placement: 'top',
                align: 'left',
                donetext: 'Done'
            });
}
</script>
```

but I am getting the below error

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).clockpicker is not a function

Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance

Comment: Where are you including `colorpicker` plugin reference in html?

Comment: Colorpicker is not included in jQuery, it's a separate plugin you need to use.

Comment: I have got the solution by using the below references
`  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://weareoutman.github.io/clockpicker/dist/jquery-clockpicker.min.css"/>
          <script src="https://weareoutman.github.io/clockpicker/dist/jquery-clockpicker.min.js"></script>
`

Answer (score 0):

```js
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/clockpicker/0.0.7/bootstrap-clockpicker.js"></script>
```